# Finding values in "IN" clause that do not match a record

Tags: sql, hibernate

I have a `dept` table with `eng` and `finance` records. It does not contain records for `foo`, `bar` or `baz`. I have  a hibernate query that returns the records that match what I am looking for. It looks like:

```
select * from dept where dept.name in (eng, foo, bar, baz, finance);
```

The query is working fine and does what I need it to do (finds `eng` and `finance`).  However, I also need to print out a log message for those that match no record ( `foo`, `bar`,  and `baz`):

```js
log.debug ("could not find records where dept.name in foo, bar, baz");
```

Is there an easy way to do this in hibernate?

From what I can see, the only solution is to make some structure with all of the hypothetical values and remove the things that the query found.

Answer (score 3):

As [a_horse_with_no_name points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16471825/241211), you didn't state your DBMS. This is a SQL Server 2008 solution:

```
select input.name
from (values
    ('eng'),
    ('foo'),
    ('bar'),
    ('baz'),
    ('finance')
)[input](name)

left join depts d on d.name = input.name
where d.name is null
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't state your DBMS, so this is ANSI SQL:

```
with names (dname) as (
  values 
     ('eng'), 
     ('foo'),
     ('bar'),
     ('baz'),
     ('finance')
)
select n.dname 
from names as n
   left join depts as d on d.name = n.dname
where d.name is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from dept where dept.name not in (eng, foo, bar, baz, finance)
```

Comment: but since there are no records it should return 0 rows  Not that there were no records for foo bar or baz

Comment: can you elaborate more? i am confused - perhaps show some sample data and a sample output.?

Comment: I need to know which things in the "in" clause that do not match any records.  what you have here is give me all records that are not in XXXX

Comment: The in clause may or may not match records.  I need to know which of the values of the "IN" clause do not match any recods

Answer (score 0):

You could just CONCAT the field names, and the resulting list will have exactly what you wanna print as error:

```
select 
    dept.name as  name, 
    CONCAT(
        case 
            when !eng
            then 'eng, '
            else ''
        end,
        case 
            when !foo
            then 'foo, '
            else ''
        end,
        case 
            when !bar
            then 'bar, '
            else ''
        end,
        case 
            when !baz
            then 'baz, '
            else ''
        end,
        case 
            when !finance
            then 'finance'
            else ''
        end) as errorFields
from dept where dept.name not in (eng, foo, bar, baz, finance)
```

untested, just trying to give you the general idea, and im not quite sure if i undestand what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly there may be some dirty tricks to do which make it look like it worked directly in the query, but why make the query unmaintainable and put unnecessary business logic in data-access layer? It is extremely straight-forward to be done in code.

In pseudo code it is just something like:

```java
List<Department> searchByDeptNames(List<String> deptNames) {
    List<Department> depts = 
        session.createQuery("from dept where dept.name in (:deptNames)")
               .setParameter("deptNames", deptNames)
               .list();
    // log down unmatched dept names
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        Set<String> unmatchedDeptNames = new HashSet<String>(deptNames);
        for (Department dept : depts) {
            inputDeunmatchedDeptNames.remove(dept.getName());
        }
        logger.debug("no record found for dept names : " + unmatchedDeptNames );
    }
    return depts;
}
```

The query would be even messier if you intend to pass in the values of the `in` clause at runtime.