# show query parameters that don't select anything

Tags: sql, hibernate

I have a table with a text column and I would like to select all rows that match the list of search parameters that were provided by the user:

```
select * from value where value.text in ('Mary', 'Steve', 'Walter');
```

In addition, I want to notify the user if any of his search terms could not be found. Let's say 'Steve' does not exist in the value.text column, how can I write a query that will show 'Steve'? As that information does not exist in any table, I have no idea how it could be done using a SQL query.

The actual Hibernate code looks like this:

```
List<String> searchItemList = new ArrayList<>();
searchItemList.add("Mary");
searchItemList.add("Steve");
searchItemList.add("Walter");
Query query = em.createQuery("select v from Value as v where v.text in ( :searchitemlist )");
query.setParameter("searchitemlist", searchItemList);
List result = query.getResultList();
log.info("{}", result.size());
log.info("{}", result);
```

The searchItemList is a list of all search terms provided by the user. Can be a few hundreds lines long. The current workaround is to search the value table once for each searchItem and note all queries that return 0 rows. That is rather inefficient, surely there is a better approach? Please advise.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36802083/6572971 might be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query to get an array of search items that exist in the database

```
SELECT DISTINCT value.text from value where value.text in ('Mary', 'Steve', 'Walter');
```

after running this query, If we assume that the answer is stored in an array called ***result***, ***notExistSearchListItems*** will give you the final result

```
IEnumerable<string> notExistSearchListItems = searchItemList.Except(result);
```